# Hibernate Migration from 3 to 4 SerializableBlob Class Deprecated

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-4.x

I'm recently migrating my hibernate project from version 3 to 4. I believe 'SerializableBlob' class is deprecated in Hibernate 4. What is the equivalent class for 'SerializableBlob' in Hibernate 4.Im getting error in my workspace. Sample Code snippet placed below. Kindly suggest me the solution. Thanks in advance

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql.toString().replaceAll("PROCESS_NAME"," wfactivity.PROCESS_NAME"))
                                                        .setFirstResult(firstResult)
                                                        .setMaxResults(maxResult+1);
    List blobList = query.list();
    try {
        for (Object arr : blobList) {
                SerializableBlob blob = null;

            if (arr.getClass().isArray()) {
                blob = (SerializableBlob) Array.get(arr, 0);
            } else {
                blob = (SerializableBlob) arr;
            }

            WfActivity wfActivity = new WfActivity();
            int bytes = (int) blob.length();
            wfActivity.setDataStructure(blob.getBytes(1L, bytes));
            resultList.add(wfActivity);
        }
    } catch (SQLException exp) {
        logger.info("Error occured while converting Blob object to java byte[].........."+exp.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In new Hibernate, there is parametrised type called org.hibernate.type.SerializableToBlob type.

Look at this answer as well:
[How to express a Serializable Blob type in a hibernate mapping file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601576/how-to-express-a-serializable-blob-type-in-a-hibernate-mapping-file)